# Where can I find total returns for UK stocks

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, rate-of-return

I understand the formula for total return, i.e. year close minus year open plus dividends all divided by year open price.

But I can't seem to find the total return on Yahoo UK finance for a stock, or any other stock price website. Am I missing something here?

Where can I find total return for any given UK stock?

Answer (score 1):

The adjusted close on [Yahoo! Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?p=GOOG) includes dividends:

> **Adjusted close price adjusted for both dividends and splits.